# Creating a grid system with UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, gridview, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that I want to use as a grid. When I receive an ordered pair I want to move a CAShapeLayer circle to the appropriate spot. I have 400 UICollectionView cells to form a 20x20 grid (+, +). Is there a way to do this with UICollectionView?

This what my grid looks like…

[image: UICollectionView Grid]

The green dot represents ordered pair (12, 2). I got the dot in the right spot by guessing and checking what CGPoint would correspond with (12, 2).

Any help or suggestions are appreciated! 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your green dot a layer of the view or the collectionView?

Comment: It is of type CAShapeLayer. I add it as a subview to the collection view. @vacawama

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work assuming your grid goes to the edges of your `UICollectionView`.  You might need to adjust the `CGPoint` by half the width of your circle.

```
let width = collectionView.bounds.width

// dimensions of the grid
let xdim: CGFloat = 20
let ydim: CGFloat = 20

// the grid coordinates of your point
let x: CGFloat = 12
let y: CGFloat = 2

let point = CGPoint(x: x * width / xdim, y: (ydim - y) * width / xdim)
```